# Autohotkey Move Mouse to center of screen whenever it gets towards edge

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to leverage my mouse inside of a bluestacks app native to touch screen.  Whenever I move the mouse too far to the edge, the emulator stops responding to mouse movements.  I am hoping to create an autohotkey script that automatically "centers" the mouse upon boundary conditions so that it never reaches the edge of the screen.

A couple of problems I have seen is that the movement of the mouse is picked up whenever I tried to do a DLL call for position changes.  What do you guys think?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little script that uses ClipCursor to constrain the cursor to the active window. Use <kbd>Win+V</kbd> to toggle it on or off. You can read this topic, if you want: [[Link]](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/57067-restrict-the-mouse-move-to-area/).

```
#v::
  WinGetPos, X, Y, W, H, A
  ClipCursor(t:=!t,X,Y,X+W,Y+H)
return

ClipCursor( Confine=True, x1=0 , y1=0, x2=1, y2=1 ) {
  VarSetCapacity(R,16,0)
  NumPut(x1,&R+0)
  NumPut(y1,&R+4)
  NumPut(x2,&R+8)
  NumPut(y2,&R+12)
  Return Confine ? DllCall( "ClipCursor", UInt,&R ) : DllCall( "ClipCursor" )
}
```

Comment: I think you meant "Use `Win+V` to toggle it on or off".